# Large soql queries (over 5000 characters long) to socrata is not supporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, soql, socrata, soda

I am using SodaClient to get information from a private data set in Socrata using the following code.

```
var records = (dynamic)null;

string searchCondition = "column1='something'AND (column2='something' OR 'somethingelse') ";

var clientExport = new SodaClient("host name", "app token", "username","password");

var dataset = clientExport.GetResource<modelname>("resourceid");
var offset = 0;
var limit = 1000;

var soql = new SoqlQuery().Where(searchCondition).Offset(offset).Limit(limit);
records = dataset.Query<modelname>(soql).ToList();

return records;
```

The problem is that sometimes the 'searchCondition ' can be very large say over 5000 characters, then the Sodaclient is returning error.

How can I send large soql queries to socrata? I also tried to get information using restful calls httpclient method but it also showing errors like.

> An error occurred while sending the request. The server committed a
>   protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the length of HTTP query URLs, which `SodaClient` uses under the covers to make its RESTful API requests, is limited both by the `HTTP/1.1` specification and also by practical limits within HTTP libraries themselves. Here's another StackOverflow post with more details: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

What are you putting into your search condition? Maybe I can help you come up with a more optimized way to issue your query.

Comment: There is a 'Category'  column which have 160 distinguished values. To search this i am using the following query

Comment: There is a 'Category'  column which have 160 distinguished values. To search this field along with other columns  I am using the following query https://host/resource/xxxx-xxx.json?$where=(Category ='value1' OR Category ='value2' OR Category ='value3') AND SubCatagory = 'value1'. Please note that I cannot use the IN(..) functionality in this data set because it is a derived one, as per you said earlier for my question. So i have to relay on the OR method.